# git: pull tag, re-tag and push

Tags: git, jenkins, devops

In a jenkins pipeline, I am attempting to pull from a dev branch, tag as 't_int_dev'.
later I want to pull tag 't_int_dev' and retag as 't_int_qa' and push that.

The first part works fine:

```
checkout scmGit( branches: [[name: 'b_dev']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: creds, url: repo ]])   

sh("""git pull origin b_dev && 
      git tag -f t_int_dev && 
      git push -f origin t_int_dev""")
```

But later, when I want to pull the dev tag and retag as qa, I get an error on this line:

```
checkout scmGit( branches: [[name: 't_int_dev']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: creds, url: repo ]])
```

Jenkins error:

`ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.`

why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with the complete ref name for your target tag:

```
branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/t_int_dev']]
```

If you have a message stating that it is an unknown revision, try also setting a refspec which would instruct git to download this tag:

```
branches: [[name: 'refs/tags/t_int_dev']],
userRemoteConfigs: [
  [credentialsId: creds, url: repo],
  [refspec: '+refs/tags/t_int_dev:refs/tags/t_int_dev']
]
```

the above refspec instructs to only download the specific `t_int_dev` tag, you may use a more generic refspec:

```
# download all tags:
refspec: '+refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'

# download all branches and tags:
refspec: '+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*'
```